# DNS client not parsing NS query correctly

Tags: java, dns

i was assigned a project about writing an iterative DNS client in Java which can perform queries in A, NS, and MX registers, we were given an API to handle the DNS packets for us so we would only have to focus on the iterative nature of the program plus the logic of it

My problem occurs when i try to perform a NS query, i can go perfectly fine from the root server to an authoritative one and get the answer packet, but when i show it in terminal this happens (im showing only the last query) :
[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Esy.png)

I have no idea why this happens, but checking in wireshark, the packet seems perfectly fine, the parsing of the packet is done in their API, but my professor refuses to help me, im providing some of the code here:
My code (where i show the answers)

```
    if (!answers.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {

                NSResourceRecord nsRec = new NSResourceRecord(answers.get(i).getDomain(), answers.get(i).getTTL(),
                        new DomainName(answers.get(i).getRRData(), msg_in.toByteArray()));  // <-- The problem is here

                 System.out.println("A: " + serverDNS + " " + RRType.NS +
                 " " + nsRec.getTTL() + " "
                 + nsRec.getNS());
            }
```

The parsing part of the API:

```
 public DomainName(byte[] domain, byte[] message) {
    fromByteArray(domain, message);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String res = "";

    return labels.stream().map((label) -> label + '.').reduce(res, String::concat);        
}

private void fromByteArray(final byte[] domain, final byte[] message) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < domain.length) {
        int size = (domain[i++] & 0xff);
        if (size == 0) {
            break;
        }

        if ((size & 0xc0) == 0xc0) { // Pointer
            int offset = (domain[i++] & 0xff) + ((size & 0x3f) << 8);
            setEncodedLength(i);

            fromByteArray(Arrays.copyOfRange(message, offset, message.length), message);

            return;
        }

        String label = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(domain, i, i + size), ASCII);
        i += size;
        labels.add(label);
    }

    setEncodedLength(i);
}
```

Another thing: in some servers (NS google.com for example) works perfectly fine, in others only some times
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What im missing in the dns packet that makes the weird output in the image i provided? Or is it a error in the api code?

Comment: Are you trying to print binary fields as strings?